# What are these clips called?

Tags: fastener, identify-a-tool

I need some clips that fit on the ends of rods that look like:
[image: clips]

Do they have a more common name than 'omega clips'? I can't find much if I search for that name.

Comment: They are a bit odd, so not surprising you find limited results. **C** or **E** clips are far more common in my experience for this job, particularly if the rod has a groove in it. Or cotter pins that involve a hole though the rod.

Comment: *spring clip* ... https://www.mscdirect.com/industrialtools/spring-clip.html

Comment: It's kinda like an E clip but they're made from pressed sheet metal, not wire.  So that's not correct.

Answer (score 8):

Omega clips is pretty much what they are called and googling it came up with this.
https://www.bresco.com/acatalog/Omega-Clips.html

[image]

Comment: McMaster seems to call them 'Hairpin Clips" for a different term: https://www.mcmaster.com/products/clips/hairpin-clips-5/

Comment: @Ecnerwal I think this comment qualifies as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Ultimately, they are **Cotter** pins in the US. A true cotter pin is straight, though, so they are often put in the subset of **Hairpin Cotter** pins or just **Hairpin**.

I see that Home Depot also calls them **Hitch** pins.

Comment: (zinc-plated) *spring steel hairpin clip*